# What is a good way to save high dimensional data so it doesn't run every time?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following code, which computes cosine similarity of the descriptions of tv shows and movies.

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        doc = nlp(row['description'])
        similarities[i] = {}
    #     print(row['title'])
        for j, row2 in df.iterrows():
            doc2 = nlp(row2['description'])
            #print(f"{row['title']} x {row2['title']}: {doc.similarity(doc2):.10f}")
            similarities[i][j] = doc.similarity(doc2)
```

I've also written this function, which takes as arguments two titles and returns their similarity

```
def lookup(title1, title2):
    return similarities[lookup_by_title(title1)][lookup_by_title(title2)]
```

my issue is that the dataframe I loop through has 4884 rows, so I'm have a list of 23.8 million computations. So I'm wondering what the best way is to run the computations *once* and save that information somewhere efficiently.

Comment: "So I'm wondering what the best way is to run the computations once and save that information somewhere efficiently." I don't understand. How is the `similarities` data not already the exact saved information you want?

Comment: I should have been more clear about my end goal, sorry. I want to save the following information to a df: show/movie title, the title it's being compared to, and the similarity score. My end goal is to have a function that will take as a parameter a title, and return x titles that have most similar descriptions. I thought that a dataframe would be the easiest way to do this, but I'm new to python and welcome any alternative suggestions of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you calculate `similarities` at the first time, you can dump it to a local file, and then in the next times, instead of doing the computations again, just load `similarities` from the file.

You can use `pickle` for this, See a nice tutorial [here](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-save-and-load-objects-to-and-from-file-in-python-via-facilities-from-the-pickle-module/).

I'm copying the samples in case the webpage won't be available in future. In your case, of course you need to replace `config_dictionary` with `similarities`:

**Dump:**

```
# Step 1
import pickle
 
config_dictionary = {'remote_hostname': 'google.com', 'remote_port': 80}
 
# Step 2
with open('config.dictionary', 'wb') as config_dictionary_file:
 
  # Step 3
  pickle.dump(config_dictionary, config_dictionary_file)
```

**Load:**

```
# Step 1
import pickle
 
# Step 2
with open('config.dictionary', 'rb') as config_dictionary_file:
 
    # Step 3
    config_dictionary = pickle.load(config_dictionary_file)
 
    # After config_dictionary is read from file
    print(config_dictionary)
```